# Bottom-up TileList in Flex 3.5

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flex3

In Flex 3.5, is it possible to use mx.controls.listClasses.TileList to layout tiles horizontally and bottom up?  The first part is easy - TileList.direction = TileBaseDirection.HORIZONTAL.  But what about bottom up instead of from the top down?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you'll have to write something custom to get this to work. I know you mentioned you were working in Flex 3.5, but here are some links that may be of use to you in getting started.

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/spark_layouts.html

[How to bottom-align cells in a DataGroup using TileLayout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3089884/flex-4-how-to-bottom-align-cells-in-a-datagroup-using-tilelayout)

[how do I make a TileGroup layout that has the jaggy edge on top?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094431/how-do-i-make-a-tilegroup-layout-that-has-the-jaggy-edge-on-top)