# bottom to top TileLayout

Tags: apache-flex, flex4.5, flex-spark

I need a TileLayout rendering elements bottom to top and right to left. Something like this:
[image: example]

I managed to trick the TileLayout for the "right to left" part, by setting the 'layoutDirection' attribute of my container to "rtl", but there is no equivalence for the vertical rendering.

```
<s:Group layoutDirection="rtl">
    <s:layout>
        <s:TileLayout columnWidth="250" horizontalGap="8"/>
    </s:layout>

    <!-- etc -->    
    <s:Group id="fakeGroup3" layoutDirection="ltr"/>
    <s:Group id="fakeGroup2" layoutDirection="ltr"/>
    <s:Group id="fakeGroup1" layoutDirection="ltr"/>

</s:Group>
```

Is there a simple way to achieve this? Or should I override TileLayout?!?

Comment: I would recommend to just override the tilelayout or create a custom layout based on it.

Comment: That's what I did, eventually. I had to copy the whole TileLayout code to create my own Layout...
This post was helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3089884/how-to-bottom-align-cells-in-a-datagroup-using-tilelayout

Answer (score 0):

You can anchor your Tile layout group to the bottom of the page:

```
<s:Group width="100%" height="100%" id="outermostLayoutContainer">
    <s:Group layoutDirection="rtl" width="100%" bottom="0">
        <s:layout>
            <s:TileLayout columnWidth="250" horizontalGap="8"/>
        </s:layout>

        <!-- etc -->    
        <s:Group id="fakeGroup3" layoutDirection="ltr"/>
        <s:Group id="fakeGroup2" layoutDirection="ltr"/>
        <s:Group id="fakeGroup1" layoutDirection="ltr"/>

    </s:Group>
</s:Group>
```

The inner Group with `bottom="0"` will push up towards the top of the screen based on its children.

Comment: Even like this the TileLayout will fill the first top row before putting elements in the second row.

What I need is the layout to fill the **first bottom row** and then put the excess elements on the rows above.

Comment: You can add `<s:Spacer />` as the first element in your list of `fakeGroup` elements.  Would that do the trick?